# How to get values from below string using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am a beginner to regex.

I have below String:

```
Hi Welcome to my site. #binid:BIN-4 #lat:23.025243 #long:72.5980293 #nottype:assign
```

Output Map : Get Map which contains all key-values as below:

bindid - BIN-4 (key=bindid, value=BIN-4)

lat - 23.025243

long - 72.5980293

nottype - assign

Comment: Why are you replacing the key instead of splitting on colon? Also, where is your map?

Comment: I don't see anything more than [`\B(#[^\s:]+):(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/j6Y8Ha/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find `#`, capture 1+ word chars after in the first group, match `:`, and then capture 1+ non-whitespace chars into the second group:

```
String str = "Hi Welcome to my site. #binid:BIN-4 #lat:23.025243 #long:72.5980293 #nottype:assign";
Map<String, String> res = new HashMap<String, String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#(\\w+):(\\S+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find()) {
    res.put(m.group(1),m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + " - " + m.group(2)); // Demo output
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/AhfG26).

Output:

```
binid - BIN-4
lat - 23.025243
long - 72.5980293
nottype - assign
```

**Pattern details**:

- `#` -  a `#` symbol
- `(\\w+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more word chars
- `:` - a colon
- `(\\S+)`- Capturing group 2: one or more non-whitespace chars

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/EF9Anz/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below approach for this:

```
String s = "Hi Welcome to my site. #binid:BIN-4 #lat:23.025243 #long:72.5980293 #nottype:assign";
        String startsWithHash = s.substring(s.indexOf('#')+1);
        String arr[] = startsWithHash.split("#");
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(element -> map.put(element.split(":")[0], element.split(":")[1]));

        System.out.println(map.toString());
```

***O/P:***

```
{binid=BIN-4 , nottype=assign, lat=23.025243 , long=72.5980293 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can extend your regex in next way:
1) initial split to get pairs (as you do it now)
2) for every pair perform another split by `:` which will give you first element as key and second element as value

code snippet:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        String input = "Hi Welcome to my site. #binid:BIN-4 #lat:23.025243 #long:72.5980293 #nottype:assign";
        String systemData = input.replace("Hi Welcome to my site. ", "");
        Arrays.asList(systemData.split("#")).forEach(pair -> {
            if (!pair.isEmpty()) {
                String[] split = pair.split(":");
                result.put(split[0], split[1]);
            }
        });

        result.entrySet().forEach( pair -> System.out.println("key: " + pair.getKey() + " value: " + pair.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Result:

*key: binid value: BIN-4*

*key: nottype value: assign*

*key: lat value: 23.025243*

*key: long value: 72.5980293*